# Android Studio Error: Could not initialize class com.intellij.psi.jsp.JspElementType

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 3. I have worked with it smoothly a short time. But today, I can not create java class in my project. It allows me to enter java class name but I can not press OK button to complete. I have tried cleaning project, restart android studio but it still failed. I get two error messages from android studio as follows:

> Could not initialize class com.intellij.psi.jsp.JspElementType
>
> Could not initialize class com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.StdTokenSets

Does anyone have errors like me, can you help me in this case? Thanks all and sorry for my bad English grammar.

Comment: Which android studio version you are using? Last time I upgraded my studio and its showing errors with most of gradle, dependencies. So I downgrade it and it works well.

Comment: Thank bro. I am using andorid studio 3.1.1. I have fixed it. I disable all google plugin and re-enable them, then my AS work well.

Comment: Can I keep this question for people in the same situation as me, 
 Abhishek?

Comment: Its your choice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank all. I am using andorid studio 3.1.1. I have fixed it. In this case, I disable all google plugin and re-enable them, then my AS work well. I'm not sure that's the only way but I hope my answer is useful to others.